# How to escape ] (bracketright) in a Oracle SQL regexp_like query?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

To select rows which are using one of several special characters, I would like to use the regexp_like condition in my Oracle SQL query:

```
    select 1 from dual where
    regexp_like(
      'Example [0,5%] item with special characters', 
      '[\°\]\[]+'
    );
```

But this is not working for the bracket right character (']').

I already tried:

- to escape the bracket by using a backslash `\]`
- `unistr('\005D')` instead of directly using the character

but without success. It seems that it is working for any other character but not with the bracket right.

Is there a way to fix this query or have someone an explanation why escaping this character is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540):

> To specify a right bracket (]) in the bracket expression, place it first in the list

So your query should look like (note none of the characters needs to be escaped in the character class):

```
select 1 from dual where
regexp_like(
  'Example [0,5%] item with special characters', 
  '[][°]'
)
```

Output

```
1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91fa2c/3)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't need the matching list syntax (`[]`). You can just list the search characters, separated with a pipe (`|`). Square brackets need backslash escaping.

```
select 1 
from dual where
    regexp_like(
      'Example [0,5%] item with special characters', 
      '\[|\]|°'
    );
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=85ff1de46f503703f573a011a7222458)**

```
with t as (
    select 'Example [0,5%] item with special characters' v from dual
    union all select 'abc'  from dual
    union all select 'abc°' from dual
    union all select 'a[bc' from dual
    union all select 'abc]' from dual
)
select
    v,
    case when regexp_like(v, '\[|\]|°') then 'match' else 'no match' end match
from t
```

```
V                                           | MATCH   
:------------------------------------------ | :-------
Example [0,5%] item with special characters | match   
abc                                         | no match
abc°                                        | match   
a[bc                                        | match   
abc]                                        | match
```

Answer (score -1):

Focusing on your question, `'\['` works:

```
select 1
from dual
where regexp_like('Example [0,5%] item with special characters', '\[');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=29339fb98ab78dc73515cb1780c420a9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: for the bracket left its working but I also have only bracket right in my real column.. The idea was to use the regexp_like as a black list.